# Combining specific row data in R

Tags: r

Hi I have a dataset where one row presents a item in an order. One order can have more items and therefore more rows in a dataset.

data looks like:

```
    code        nr. Of items
1   252222016   5
3   252812016   1
5   252812016   1
6   253012016   1
12  253042016   20
13  253042016   20
15  253052016   1
16  253072016   3
18  253082016   4
```

I would like a result where I would summ the "nr. Of items" where there is a same "code" and write the resoult in the row. if one order has more items I would like to have a resoult written in the last row of an order and previous rows would be NAs.

how I want the final solution to look like:

```
        code    nr. Of items    result
1   252222016   5                 5
3   252812016   1                na
5   252812016   1                 2
6   253012016   1                 1
12  253042016   20               na
13  253042016   20               40
15  253052016   1                 1
16  253072016   3                 3
18  253082016   4                 4
```

I would appreciate the help!

Comment: sorry I don't quite understand the question, what is it you want?

Comment: Is the `code` order number? Then why do you have same order number, two `nr.of items` count instead of combined? If you want to sum the total number of items for each order, what's the purpose to keep some rows of NAs? what kind of information does those NA rows provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another dplyr alternative, using `ifelse` and `fromLast = TRUE`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(code) %>% 
  mutate(result = ifelse(duplicated(code, fromLast = TRUE), NA, sum(nr.Of.items)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `duplicated` function with the parameter `fromLast = TRUE`, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(code) %>% 
  mutate(new = replace(cumsum(nr. Of items), duplicated(code, fromLast = TRUE), NA))

#Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
#Groups: code [7]

#       code    nr   new
#      <int> <int> <int>
#1 252222016     5     5
#2 252812016     1    NA
#3 252812016     1     2
#4 253012016     1     1
#5 253042016    20    NA
#6 253042016    20    40
#7 253052016     1     1
#8 253072016     3     3
#9 253082016     4     4
```

Answer (score 2):

We can accomplish this using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)    # load package
df1 %>%
    group_by(code) %>%
    mutate(rownum = 1,
           c_s_rn = cumsum(rownum),
           result = ifelse(c_s_rn == max(c_s_rn), sum(items), NA)) %>%
    select(-rownum, -c_s_rn)

#        code items result
# 1 252222016     5      5
# 2 252812016     1     NA
# 3 252812016     1      2
# 4 253012016     1      1
# 5 253042016    20     NA
# 6 253042016    20     40
# 7 253052016     1      1
# 8 253072016     3      3
# 9 253082016     4      4
```

There's also a base `R` solution using `lapply` and `split`:

```
df1_2 <- df1
df1_2$rownum <- 1
do.call('rbind',
lapply(split(df1_2, df1_2$code), function(x)
    data.frame(x, 
               result = ifelse(cumsum(x$rownum) == sum(x$rownum), sum(x$items), NA)))
)[,-3]

#                   code items result
# 252222016    252222016     5      5
# 252812016.3  252812016     1     NA
# 252812016.5  252812016     1      2
# 253012016    253012016     1      1
# 253042016.12 253042016    20     NA
# 253042016.13 253042016    20     40
# 253052016    253052016     1      1
# 253072016    253072016     3      3
# 253082016    253082016     4      4
```

#### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(
    code = c(252222016L, 252812016L, 252812016L, 253012016L, 
             253042016L, 253042016L, 253052016L, 253072016L, 253082016L), 
    items = c(5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L)), 
    .Names = c("code", "items"), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c("1", "3", "5", "6", "12", "13", "15", "16", "18"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'code', `if` the number of rows is greater than 1 (`.N >1`), then replicate `NA` by one less than the number of rows and concatenate (`c(`) with `sum` of 'items' or `else` return 'items'.  Assign (`:=` the output to create the new column 'result'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, result := if(.N>1) c(rep(NA, .N-1), sum(items)) else items, by = code]
df1
#        code items result
#1: 252222016     5      5
#2: 252812016     1     NA
#3: 252812016     1      2
#4: 253012016     1      1
#5: 253042016    20     NA
#6: 253042016    20     40
#7: 253052016     1      1
#8: 253072016     3      3
#9: 253082016     4      4
```

---

Or instead of using the `if/else` we can also create NA on positions other than the last row and multiply with the `sum` of 'items'

```
setDT(df1)[, result := NA^(seq_len(.N) != .N)*sum(items) , by = code]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(
code = c(252222016L, 252812016L, 252812016L, 253012016L, 
         253042016L, 253042016L, 253052016L, 253072016L, 253082016L), 
items = c(5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L)), 
.Names = c("code", "items"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "3", "5", "6", "12", "13", "15", "16", "18"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `dplyr` package (using `df1` of @bouncyball) is :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(code) %>% mutate(result=ifelse(row_number()==n(),sum(items),NA))
```